# I have different versions of javac and java. I'm trying to run my .java file on terminal. But it works in eclipse

Tags: java

How to resolve this? I can compile it but I can't run it. I have different versions of `javac` and `java`. I'm trying to run my `.java` file on terminal. But it works in eclipse. I know that version affects this. How to upgrade `javac`? Will it affect my eclipse if I do so? Thanks. ;)

```
[clemjon@localhost ~]$ javac -version

javac 1.6.0_20


[clemjon@localhost ~]$ java -version

java version "1.6.0_21"
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Using a Java version that is newer than the compiler version should always work. The other way around has a number of caveats.

Comment: [root@localhost casestudy]# javac First.java

[root@localhost casestudy]# java First

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: First (wrong name: com/pl/casestudy/First)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at

Comment: java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: First.  Program will exit.

Comment: Please don't post stacktraces in comments.  Please edit your question and add the stacktrace there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue to do with different versions of `javac` and `java`.  The problem here is that you are attempting to run a class file whose fully-qualified name (`com.pl.casestudy.First`) doesn't match the class name you passed to `java` (`First`).  You would get the same error if you had the same versions of `javac` and `java`.

If you have a class whose name is `com.pl.casestudy.First`, Java will look for it in a file with name `com/pl/casestudy/First.class` (Windows users feel free to reverse the direction of the slashes.)  So you will need to run your `First` class from the directory that contains the `com` subdirectory.  I can see from the shell prompt in your stacktrace that you have a directory named `casestudy`, I'll assume that the `com` and `pl` parent directories also exist.  Eclipse has probably created them for you.

Try `cd`ing out to the directory that contains `com`, compiling using

```
javac com/pl/casestudy/First.java
```

and running using

```
java com.pl.casestudy.First
```

Comment: No need to reverse the slashes - the normal slashes work just fine. Unfortunately, this knowledge is one of the lesser known secrets of Windows. It is perpetuated with an enormous amount of newbie code where filenames are spelled like "foo\\bar\\baz".

Comment: @Ingo: `com/pl/casestudy/First.class` is just the name of a file, it's not code.  Its sole purpose is to guide the questioner to the location where Java expects to find the file.  If a Windows user is more familiar with the backslash as a directory separator, they are free to reverse the direction of the slashes.  I'm well aware that forward slashes work on Windows, but that is beside the point.

Comment: I know, just saying. Yet, a lot of problems with hard-coded path names could go away if Windows users would get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check which JRE eclipse is using:

`Window->Preferences->Java->JREs` 
Right click the selected one and `Edit`.
The JRE home path should be there. Add that path to your `path` environment variable  (instead of the one that is already there) and that should do the trick for you.

You can also set which JDK version you want Eclipse to compile to:
`Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler`

My best advice would be to keep track of all the installed JDK's and JRE's.

Choose the ones you want to use by default and add those to your `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` environment variables; Then setup your Eclipse to the same values using the steps above.

Then if for a particular project you need to use a specific JRE, right click on that project and then go to `BuildPath`->`Libraries`->`JRE 
Library`->`Edit` and pick you JRE.

Disclaimer: I'm not on my dev machine right now so the names may be approximate. :)

Comment: is this in eclipse? in my eclipse, java files are runnable. I'm trying it on terminal but it doesn't work.

Comment: No you *java* files are not runnable.

Comment: i mean the compiled one sir.